# $X=Poi(\lambda)$ and $Y=Geom(p)$ and $Y$ is independent Geometric. Give a formula for $P(X=Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

$X=Poi(\lambda)$ and $Y=Geom(p)$ and $Y$ is independent Geometric. Give a formula for $P(X=Y)$

No Idea how to do this
$Y=(1-p)^kp$
$X=e^{-\lambda}(\lambda^n/n!)$

and I'm assuming it's asking for this?
$(1-p)^kp=e^{-\lambda}(\lambda^n/n!)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X=Y)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{k} e^{-\lambda} \frac  {\lambda ^{k}} {k!}$. This is  nothing  but $pe^{-\lambda} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {r^{k}} {k!}$ where $r=(1-p)\lambda$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How does multiplying them together give $P(X=Y)$?

Comment: The events $X=Y=k$ are mutually exclusive and their union is the event $X=Y$. Hence $P(X=Y)$ is the sum of  the numbers $P(X=Y=k)$. By independence we can write $P(X=Y=k)=P(X=k)P(Y=k)$. @DylanY